# How to get all document from a collection using mongoDB and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need one help.i want to fetch all data from a collection using mongoDB and Node.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
exports.readProfileData=function(req,res){
    db.profile.findOne({
        colgid:1
    },{
        colgname:1,
        colgSname:1,
        address:1,
        contno:1,
        email:1
    },function(err,docs){
        if(!err){
            if(docs){
                res.send(docs);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In this code i am fetching single document from profile collection but i need to fetch all document present in profile collection and send it to client side.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find({})` this will catch all:

```
exports.readProfileData=function(req,res){
    db.profile.find({},{
        colgname:1,
        colgSname:1,
        address:1,
        contno:1,
        email:1
    },function(err,docs){
        if(!err){
            if(docs){
                res.send(docs);
            }
        }
    });
}
```